# postgresql replication + scrubbing

Tags: postgresql, replication, etl, pci-compliance

Is there any an easy (built-in, add-on, open-source or commercial) to do replication on Postgresql (Master-slave) to have the data inside the slave be scrubbed for PCI compliance while being replicated across?  How about ETL tools?  It does not have to be instantaneous ... up to an hour lag is acceptable but the faster the better of course.

If this doesn't work, how about possibly using triggers on the slave database to achieve this?

Comment: What sort of data would you imagine requires scrubbing for PCI compliance?  If you're already storing data that's out of compliance with PCI, what does scrubbing it during replication get you?

Comment: The scrubbing is for moving data back into a data warehouse application which may be exposed to outside parties.  SSNs and personally identifiable information is the main goal of the scrub.  The data warehouse is designed to only show aggregate data.

Comment: On the surface, it doesn't sound like a problem solved well by replication.  Have you considered putting only aggregate data in the slave database?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should try creating a view of the tables you wish to scrub (performing your scrubbing in the SELECT), and then replicate the view to your offsite location.

Answer (score 1):

I believe triggers on the slave would put you at risk for non-compliance, since data could leak out. If you want a packaged solution, I'd probably look at Bucardo, looking specifically into doing custom replication hooks into slave, to filter out (or modify) the columns you don't need/want. If that won't work, the idea to use views is probably your next best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Use slony, add triggers to the master to materialize what you want to replicate and replicate only those materialized views.  If you scrub on the master, that should do what you want.  Since Slony will happily replicate only part of your database, that should work fine (on the other hand, remember, Slony will happily replicate only part of your database).